How do I make this expression in one line?
How do I make this expression in one line ?
$ (\forall (a ; b ) \in \mathbb{R}^{2})
(\forall (x ; y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2})
;
(a ; b )\star(x ; y) = \left(\dfrac{ax + by}{2};\dfrac{ay + bx}{2}\right)
$ 



Welcome to TeX.SX! We don't know anything about your document, so how should we help you here? You could use a larger paper size maybe, so the math fits in one line, but this is probably not what you want. Please help us help you and provide a minimal working example (MWE). Thank you!

Welcome to TeX!SE! Make your text width sufficient large or reduce font size so much, that equation will be able fit in one line.  Anyway, please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example`, a small but complete document which reproduce your problem. So far we hqvewn't any information about your document layout,.

an expression that large would normally be a display \[ not inline $ and such a display is always one line

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)
There seems to be no problem displaying the formula on a single line when using the article document class, Computer Modern text and math fonts, and a 12pt basic font size.

The vertical lines at the edges of the screenshot are drawn because the showframe package is loaded.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{showframe} % display framelines around text block

\begin{document}
\[
(\forall (a ; b ) \in \mathbb{R}^{2})
(\forall (x ; y ) \in \mathbb{R}^{2});
(a ; b )\star(x ; y) = 
\biggl(\frac{ax + by}{2};\frac{ay + bx}{2}\biggr)
\]
\end{document}

